# What is best coding approach for realtime noise cancelation in a conference?

Tags: audio, recurrent-neural-network, noise, noise-reduction, conference

I have searched and found a lot of noise-canceling solutions. but many of them are platform-dependent(like "noise torch" for ubuntu) and many of them are not workable for real-time. I also looked into some RNN(recurrent neural network) based [solution](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/rnnoise) but none of this is that good or hard to integrate.

now, for an audio conference situation, especially targeted to an office environment(any formal conference mainly), what approach should I follow for denoising audio(audio byte array for example) per participant? or what is the best open-source (may need some tweaking) solution/approach available to date which is platform-independent?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help..!!

Comment: update your question to detail examples of source of such noise

Comment: I updated.. actually I need noise cancelation especially for a formal conference situation like skype you can say. There are different kinds of noise falling in this area and noise prioritization would be determined by the method I will use, isn't it? this is a vast area I am exploring but don't know why no one is responding. should I specify more? if so please tell me